# jquery to pure javascript ul li button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm looking for help converting this jquery code to pure javascript

```
$(".list .btn").click(function(){
   $(".list li").removeClass("menuActive");
   $(this).parent().addClass("menuActive");
});

$(".popup").click(function(){
   $(".list li").removeClass("menuActive");
}); 

  <div id="button-row">
<ul class="list">
  <li class=" ">
    <button class="btn">click</button>
     <div class="popup"></div>
  </li>
  <li class=""><button class="btn">click</button>2 <div class="popup"></div></li>
  <li class=""><button class="btn">click</button>3 <div class="popup"></div></li>
</ul>
```

I don't really want to add jquery to my site, i need a pure javascript solution.

Comment: This might be useful, -> http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#delegate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a plain JS delegation

```js
const list = document.querySelector("#button-row .list");
const resetLI = () => [...list.querySelectorAll("li")].forEach(li => li.classList.remove("menuActive"));

list.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("btn")) {
    resetLI();
    tgt.closest("li").classList.add("menuActive");
  } else if (tgt.classList.contains("popup")) {
    resetLI();
  }
});
```

```css
.menuActive {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<div id="button-row">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class=" ">
      <button class="btn">click</button> 1
      <div class="popup">Pop</div>
    </li>
    <li class=""><button class="btn">click</button> 2
      <div class="popup">Pop</div>
    </li>
    <li class=""><button class="btn">click</button> 3
      <div class="popup">Pop</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```